# How to calculate the average age of a subgroup

Tags: group-differences, mean

Just to confirm my findings to a group of data scientists...

I have a data set with patients visits and among others the death age of deceased patients. If I then look up all diagnoses the patients had had and count the average death age X of patients with a certain diagnose (if a patient had diagnose A, his death age will be in the calculation for the average death age of patients with diagnose A, if he also had diagnose B, he will be in calculation of average  death age of diag B as well, and so on...),

Is it (Isn't it?) ok to say that "patients with diagnose A died on average at age X"?

The data quality is high, and the data set is complete, including all patient data for patients in a certain hospital district and with these diagnoses. On general level (for common diagnoses) the average death age corresponds to the average death age of the population.

It is just the death ages of certain diagnoses and patient groups ("if they also had diagnose C and/or D") are puzzling the audience and so I would need some conforming on this or ideas on how to estimate the average age if this is not the right way. For some groups the number of patients in a subset is very low but the "death ages" are still in line with bigger subgroups of the same diagnose.

All ideas appreciated.

Comment: I'm struggling to see why this wouldn't be okay. If you are honest and say "this is average age of death for those in diagnost A" there's no ethical or computational reason you can't do this.

Comment: It would be perfectly fine to say, on average, patients with diagnosis A died on average at age X. There's information there, but an issue of course is the interpretation. To what extent is disease causing age of death? Or to what extent is age causing disease? I'm not sure how they do it, but my impression is that a lot of NIH statistics try to compute some age adjusted death rate?

Comment: There is an obvious censoring mechanism in there, the ones with diagnosis A which lives long and did'nt die yet is missing, so you get to many in your group which lived shorter.  That complicates things.

Comment: There is also a sampling bias or noncoverage error here.  The OP writes "the average death age corresponds to the average death age of the population."  I'm not sure you can say this without examining death certificates.  It's quite possible that some, especially in low income areas do not seek treatment or may not visit a hospital for death.  This is especially true with diseases where socioeconomic status is a risk factor. If we assume that this is not the case, taking averages is fine for descriptive statements.  But all causal statements with these types of analyses are out of question

Comment: It's not really clear to me what your OBJECTIVE is here.  Can you clearly state what is is that you are trying to show?  Is there some sort of causal component you are trying to show as @MatthewGunn has suggested? Also jketil makes a great point.  It think you may want to revise your definition to be, of those who have died, X, have died of diagnosis A.

Comment: Isn't there usually a primary diagnosis and associated final APR-DRG code associated with each patient?  Is it unreasonable to use that?"

Answer (score 1):

How many diagnoses do you have? I not many, you could divide patients in groups of all combinations of diagnoses.

For example:

```
- patient 1 has diag A
- patient 2 has diag B
- patient 3 has diag A and B
- patient 4 has diag B and C
- patient 5 has diag A
- patient 6 has diag A and B
```

For this data, I am proposing the following groups:

```
Group 1: diag A
 - patient 1
 - patient 5

Group 2: diag B
 - patient 2

Group 3: diag A and B
 - patient 3
 - patient 6

Group 4: diag B and C
 - patient 4
```

If you do not have a lot of diagnoses and a lot of people with weird combinations of diagnoses, this would be feasible. This way you eliminate the effect of multiple diagnoses on a persons' life expectancy. Also, you could calculate the average lifespan of people with a certain combination of diagnoses (e.g. A and B).

Comment: Thanks! Actually there are thousands of patients with many different combinations of diagnoses... And in addition some have a hundred visits of diagnose A, a few of B and one of C and another patient many B, but only one of A and D and so on... but actually I've done it quite like you suggested, just that I had two diagnose groups as subgroups (C&D) and calculated the average death ages for all diagnoses given these subgroups.

Comment: If patients have a lot of different diagnoses and only a few with a lot of occurences... maybe you could use some concepts from Fuzzy Logic, where group membership is not exact, but _fuzzy_.